# Undefined Reference when OpenCV libraries cross compiled in Eclipse for Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, gcc, cross-compiling

I am cross-compiling OpenCV libraries (2.4.9) and Raspicam (0.1.3) in Eclipse CDT IDE for Raspberry Pi. I am trying to compile a basic application that looks as the following:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <raspicam.h>
#include <raspicam_cv.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
....

    namedWindow(output_window_name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow(grayscale_window_name, 100);
    namedWindow(thresholded_window_name, 100);
    namedWindow(contours_window_name, 100);

    moveWindow(grayscale_window_name, 20,20);
    moveWindow(thresholded_window_name, 20, 250);
    moveWindow(contours_window_name, 20, 600);


    vector<int> compression_params;
    compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
    compression_params.push_back(100);

    raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv Camera;
....


}
```

To compile I made sure that `libopencv_*.so` files are in the cross compilation sysroot and linked in Eclipse using `-l` flags such as `-lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui` etc. I also included every `include/` folder in sources using -I flag in Eclipse Build Settings.

Inclusion using `#include` and `namespace` declarations do not result in any errors.

Target building looks like this in the console:

```
     arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ 
     -L"C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib"
     -L"C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
     -L"C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\libbluetooth"
     -L"C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\lib"
     -Wl,-rpath-link,"C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf" 
    -o "RaspberryTest"  ./src/<ALL OBJS>
    -lwiringPi 
    -lopencv_calib3d 
    -lopencv_core 
    -lopencv_features2d 
    -lopencv_flann 
    -lopencv_highgui 
    -lopencv_imgproc 
    -lopencv_ml 
    -lopencv_objdetect 
    -lopencv_video 
    -lbluetooth 
    -lpthread 
    -lwiringPiDev
```

However, the following errors are there:

```
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:115: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:116: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:117: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:118: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:120: undefined reference to `cv::moveWindow(std::string const&, int, int)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:121: undefined reference to `cv::moveWindow(std::string const&, int, int)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:122: undefined reference to `cv::moveWindow(std::string const&, int, int)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:129: undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv::RaspiCam_Cv()'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:131: undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv::open()'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:194: undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv::grab()'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:195: undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv::retrieve(cv::Mat&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:208: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:208: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:211: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:211: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:215: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:215: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:219: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:219: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:220: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:220: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:220: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:224: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:224: undefined reference to `cv::floodFill(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double>, cv::Rect_<int>*, cv::Scalar_<double>, cv::Scalar_<double>, int)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:228: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:228: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:233: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:233: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:238: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:238: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:240: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:240: undefined reference to `cv::findContours(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int, cv::Point_<int>)'
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\Debug/../src/tasks/image_processing_task.cpp:129: undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv::~RaspiCam_Cv()'
./src/tasks/image_processing_task.o: In function `cv::Mat::clone() const':
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\opencv-2.4.9\modules\core\include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:335: undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
./src/tasks/image_processing_task.o: In function `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Scalar_<double> const&)':
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\opencv-2.4.9\modules\core\include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1137: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
./src/tasks/image_processing_task.o: In function `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray<cv::Point_<int> >(std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > >&)':
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\opencv-2.4.9\modules\core\include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1145: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_OutputArray'
./src/tasks/image_processing_task.o: In function `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray<cv::Vec<int, 4> >(std::vector<cv::Vec<int, 4>, std::allocator<cv::Vec<int, 4> > >&)':
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\opencv-2.4.9\modules\core\include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1143: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_OutputArray'
./src/tasks/image_processing_task.o: In function `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray<cv::Point_<int> >(std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > const&)':
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\opencv-2.4.9\modules\core\include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1122: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
./src/tasks/image_processing_task.o: In function `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray<cv::Point_<int> >(std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >&)':
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\opencv-2.4.9\modules\core\include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1143: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_OutputArray'
./src/tasks/image_processing_task.o: In function `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray<cv::Point_<int> >(std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > > const&)':
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\opencv-2.4.9\modules\core\include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1125: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
./src/tasks/image_processing_task.o: In function `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray<cv::Vec<int, 4> >(std::vector<cv::Vec<int, 4>, std::allocator<cv::Vec<int, 4> > > const&)':
C:\rpi-eclipse\workspace\RaspberryTest\opencv-2.4.9\modules\core\include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1122: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [RaspberryTest] Error 1
```

This indicates that I have two type of errors.

**1-)** undefined reference (for functions)

**2-)** undefined reference to vtable` (Related to virtual functions I believe)

In order to overcome this problem, I feel like I have to change STL/C standards, but do not know what to do exactly. Also, the fact that libraries are compiled and included correctly but there are still undefined references is really weird to me.

Any guidance regarding how to solve this problem is greately appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was your OpenCV compiled for ARM architecture? I think you're trying to link OpenCV libraries built for x86-64 in a program compiling for ARM.

Comment: I copied .so libraries from Raspberry Pi (ARM). But regardless, without the linking even including libraries should work. I think there is a different problem here.

Comment: @mozcelikors Have you found the solution?

Comment: Which one 1, or 2?